# Connect/Pair Bluetooth Headset and Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to create a simple program that scans for a bluetooth headset (I'm testing with a PS3 headset) and then connect to it.  I'm using the code from the [bluetooth chat program example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html).  However I cannot get it to connect to anything.  It is giving me an I/O Exception when it gets to the connect().

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either succeeds or fails.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
        if (tmp == null){
            Log.i(TAG, "tmp is NULL");
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Log.i(TAG, "discovery is cancelled");
        
        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();  //Doesn't like something here???
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IO error, ", e);
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            newTBluetoothService.this.start();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (newBluetoothService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

---

```
10-13 16:07:45.544: ERROR/BluetoothService.cpp(1259): 
stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)

10-13 16:07:45.544: DEBUG/newBluetoothService(2821): connect to: 00:22:A6:07:12:2B

10-13 16:07:45.544: DEBUG/newBluetoothService(2821): setState() 0 -> 2

10-13 16:07:45.552: INFO/newBluetoothService(2821): BEGIN mConnectThread

10-13 16:07:45.567: ERROR/BluetoothService.cpp(1259): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)

10-13 16:07:45.567: INFO/newBluetoothService(2821): discovery is cancelled

10-13 16:07:45.575: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(1259): onCreateDeviceResult: D-Bus error: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists (Device already exists)

10-13 16:07:45.583: INFO/BluetoothNew(2821): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 2

10-13 16:07:46.700: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(1259): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/2872/hci0/dev_00_22_A6_07_12_2B

10-13 16:07:47.036: DEBUG/BluetoothService(1259): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:22:A6:07:12:2B)

10-13 16:07:47.059: DEBUG/BluetoothService(1259):     uuid(system): 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 1

10-13 16:07:47.067: DEBUG/BluetoothService(1259):     uuid(system): 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 2

10-13 16:07:47.075: VERBOSE/BluetoothEventRedirector(1786): Received android.bleutooth.device.action.UUID

10-13 16:07:47.075: DEBUG/BluetoothService(1259): Cleaning up failed UUID channel lookup: 00:22:A6:07:12:2B 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

10-13 16:07:47.083: ERROR/newBluetoothService(2821): IO error, 

10-13 16:07:47.083: ERROR/newBluetoothService(2821): java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed

10-13 16:07:47.083: ERROR/newBluetoothService(2821):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:377)

10-13 16:07:47.083: ERROR/newBluetoothService(2821):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:201)

10-13 16:07:47.083: ERROR/newBluetoothService(2821):     at com.nmtransfer.bluetooth.newBluetoothService$ConnectThread.run(newBluetoothService.java:347)

10-13 16:07:47.083: INFO/newBluetoothService(2821): Connection Failed

10-13 16:07:47.083: DEBUG/newBluetoothService(2821): setState() 2 -> 1

10-13 16:07:47.083: DEBUG/newBluetoothService(2821): start

10-13 16:07:47.083: INFO/BluetoothNew(2821): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 1

10-13 16:07:47.098: DEBUG/BluetoothService(1259): new handle 1000d

10-13 16:07:47.106: DEBUG/newBluetoothService(2821): setState() 1 -> 1

10-13 16:07:47.106: DEBUG/newBluetoothService(2821): BEGIN mAcceptThreadThread[Thread-
13,5,main]

10-13 16:07:47.114: INFO/BluetoothNew(2821): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 1

10-13 16:07:51.036: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(1259): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/2872/hci0/dev_00_22_A6_07_12_2B

10-13 16:07:53.583: VERBOSE/BluetoothEventRedirector(1786): Received android.bleutooth.device.action.UUID
```

---

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you
Chris

Comment: I'm testing on a Droid X with the 2.2 update and a PS3 Bluetooth headset.  It is being paired but will not connect.  I can manually connect the headset when I go into the bluetooth settings.

Answer (score 2):

@CHRIS Hey i actually just figured out the problem. You hit the nail on the head with the connectThread, however you need to use the UUID("00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB") for the headset profile. I'm using a Jabra headset and it works for me. Let me know if you have questions!
Thanks!

Comment: Some bluetooth headsets may not provide this profile UUID, although it is the basic profile for this purpose. But as the "higher" level profile for car kit usage adds some interesting features (redial last number, etc.) you should first try to the HandsFreeProfile (HFP) with UUID "0000111E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB".

Answer (score 1):

I thought you should not assign a specific UUID as your connecting param except that you know this is the exact GUID provided by your headset.
I'm not for sure. But I hope it could help you.

Good luck!

Fancy

Answer (score 1):

I am studying a similar issue as well ...
-- How to connect Headset profile by APP.
And then I saw this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5711736/769556

> Basically this Headset level profile connection is done internally by
>   Android (and there are no application level access to establish
>   connections)

So ...@Chris Mattmiller have you find different answer?